# Why do my font url's have ?v=4.0.3 after them in the CSS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code I have:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
  src: url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'), url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'), url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Can someone tell me what is the significance of the `?v=4.0.3` Do I need to have this?

Comment: They are versions to prevent caching.

Comment: As @JoshC said, they are for caching and you don't need them if you don't want to have them, but it's better to leave them in if you decide do update fontawesome some day.

Comment: Would it not be better just to have the font files named: fontawesome-webfont-4.0.3 and I could have them cached and update later?

Comment: @Melina yes, it would. From memory, I don't think query strings are the most reliable cache-busters. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15795803/283366

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is for caching, like the comments state. The reasoning behind not using versioning in the file name is to keep from cluttering your version control system with multiple copies or the need to create some sort of publish script that makes copies and appends version number in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the servers keeps a copy of the files which you are using,
Assume file tahoma.woff was being referred earlier and now you want to change or upgrade that font file to a newer version.
Now you replace it with an upgraded version of the same font family. Since the severs and the browsers use caching even though you have upgraded the file the webpage will be showing you the older versions.
But when you have maintained the versions and update the references of the font with changing the versions in the code you can avoid the browsers using the cached files.
You can also rename the filename and update the reference for that file, but to make it more meaningful you have to use the version number.